# When use oozie spark action, spark driver spawned on one Node can find custom log4j config file, but on other Nodes cannot find. why?

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, hadoop-yarn, oozie

Use oozie to run spark action workflow has problem.
If driver spawned on node (172.12.0.27), log config is **always right**.
If driver spawned on other nodes(172.12.0.18,172.12.0.20), log config is **always wrong**.

Use spark-submit to run job without above problem, driver spawned on every node works right.

How can I track problem?

There are three nodes(172.12.0.27,172.12.0.18,172.12.0.20). If use spark-submit with custom log4j config file, no problem on any of the node .

**spark-submit works right.**

```sh
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 1g --num-executors 4 --executor-memory 1g --files "/root/alenym/log4j.properties" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties -Dtb.spark.prod.env=true" --class com.stc.data.thingsboard.jobs.example.TestLogJob /root/alenym/dp_advance_analysis/bigdata/tb-sql-analysis/target/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**oozie workflow has wrong.**

1. workflow.xml like this below.

```xml
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.5' name='spark-test'>
    <start to='spark-node' />

    <action name='spark-node'>
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <job-xml>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/spark/hive-site.xml</job-xml>
            <master>${master}</master>
        <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>spark-test-oozie</name>
            <class>com.stc.data.thingsboard.jobs.example.TestLogJob</class>
            <jar>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/spark/lib/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar>
        <spark-opts>--driver-memory 1g --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 1g --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-ym.properties -Dtb.spark.prod.env=true </spark-opts>
        </spark>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Workflow failed, error
            message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
        </message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

2. job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://HDFS80599
jobTracker=rm1
master=yarn
queueName=default
examplesRoot=batchtest
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/spark
```

3. custom "log4j-ym.properties" file is in "./lib" directory, so that --files has include

**hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/log4j-ym.properties#log4j-ym.properties,**

```
Log Type: stdout

Log Upload Time: Mon Aug 26 10:05:44 +0800 2019

Log Length: 261750

Oozie Launcher starts



Oozie Java/Map-Reduce/Pig action launcher-job configuration
=================================================================
Workflow job id   : 0000993-190728182827383-oozie-hado-W
Workflow action id: 0000993-190728182827383-oozie-hado-W@spark-node

Classpath         :
------------------------
...
...

------------------------

Main class        : org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain

Maximum output    : 2048

Arguments         :

Java System Properties:
------------------------
#
#Mon Aug 26 10:04:54 CST 2019
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path=/usr/local/jdk/jre/lib/amd64
java.vm.version=25.191-b12
oozie.action.externalChildIDs=/data/emr/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1565412953433_3795/container_e22_1565412953433_3795_01_000002/externalChildIDs
hadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor. url=/emr-yarn-jobhistory/http://172.21.0.48:5024/http\://java.oracle.com/
path.separator=\:
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
oozie.job.launch.time=1566785085000
user.country=US
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level=unknown
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=/data/emr/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1565412953433_3795/container_e22_1565412953433_3795_01_000002
oozie.action.newId=/data/emr/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1565412953433_3795/container_e22_1565412953433_3795_01_000002/newId
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_191-b12
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/jdk/jre/lib/endorsed
os.arch=amd64
oozie.job.id=0000993-190728182827383-oozie-hado-W
oozie.action.id=0000993-190728182827383-oozie-hado-W@spark-node
yarn.app.container.log.dir=/data/emr/yarn/logs/application_1565412953433_3795/container_e22_1565412953433_3795_01_000002
java.io.tmpdir=./tmp
...
...
>>> Invoking Main class now >>>

Fetching child yarn jobs
tag id : oozie-e1db067250aafedb4df7ee644cd82ab4
Child yarn jobs are found - 
Warning: Spark Log4J settings are overwritten. Child job IDs may not be available
Spark Version 2.3
Spark Action Main class        : org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit

Oozie Spark action configuration
=================================================================

                    --master
                    yarn
                    --deploy-mode
                    cluster
                    --name
                    spark-test-oozie
                    --class
                    com.stc.data.thingsboard.jobs.example.TestLogJob
                    --conf
                    spark.oozie.action.id=0000993-190728182827383-oozie-hado-W@spark-node
                    --conf
                    spark.oozie.child.mapreduce.job.tags=oozie-e1db067250aafedb4df7ee644cd82ab4
                    --conf
                    spark.oozie.action.rootlogger.log.level=INFO
                    --conf
                    spark.oozie.job.id=0000993-190728182827383-oozie-hado-W
                    --conf
                    spark.oozie.action.spark.setup.hadoop.conf.dir=false
                    --conf
                    spark.oozie.HadoopAccessorService.created=true
                    --driver-memory
                    1g
                    --num-executors
                    10
                    --executor-memory
                    1g
                    --conf
                    spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-ym.properties -Dtb.spark.prod.env=true
                    --conf
                    spark.executor.extraClassPath=$PWD/*
                    --conf
                    spark.driver.extraClassPath=$PWD/*
                    --conf
                    spark.yarn.tags=oozie-e1db067250aafedb4df7ee644cd82ab4
                    --conf
                    spark.yarn.security.tokens.hadoopfs.enabled=false
                    --conf
                    spark.yarn.security.tokens.hive.enabled=false
                    --conf
                    spark.yarn.security.tokens.hbase.enabled=false
                    --conf
                    spark.yarn.security.credentials.hadoopfs.enabled=false
                    --conf
                    spark.yarn.security.credentials.hive.enabled=false
                    --conf
                    spark.yarn.security.credentials.hbase.enabled=false
                    --conf
                    spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=spark-log4j.properties
                    --files
                    hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/breeze_2.11-0.13.2.jar,...,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/calcite-core-1.2.0-incubating.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/calcite-linq4j-1.2.0-incubating.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/chill-java-0.8.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/chill_2.11-0.8.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/commons-compiler-3.0.8.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/commons-compress-1.9.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/commons-crypto-1.0.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-4.1.17.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.19.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/derby-10.10.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/disruptor-3.3.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/dropwizard-metrics-hadoop-metrics2-reporter-0.1.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/eigenbase-properties-1.1.5.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/fastutil-6.5.6.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/flume-ng-configuration-1.6.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/flume-ng-core-1.6.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/flume-ng-sdk-1.6.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/geronimo-jaspic_1.0_spec-1.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/gson-2.7.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/guice-3.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-common-2.8.4-tests.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-common-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.8.4-tests.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-hdfs-client-2.8.4-tests.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-hdfs-client-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-hdfs-native-client-2.8.4-tests.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-hdfs-native-client-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.8.4-tests.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-nfs-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/hadoop/share/lib/lib_20190728182750/oozie/hadoop-temrfs-1.0.6.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-api-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-client-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-common-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.7.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-timeline-pluginstorage-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.8.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hbase-annotations-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hbase-client-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hbase-common-1.1.1-tests.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hbase-common-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hbase-prefix-tree-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hbase-procedure-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hbase-server-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hive-beeline-1.2.1.spark2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hive-cli-1.2.1.spark2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hive-hbase-handler-2.3.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hive-hcatalog-core-2.3.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.1.spark2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/httpclient-4.3.6.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/httpcore-4.3.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jackson-module-paranamer-2.6.5.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.6.5.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/janino-3.0.8.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/java-xmlbuilder-1.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/javax.inject-1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/javax.jdo-3.2.0-m3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/javolution-5.5.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jcodings-1.0.8.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jcommander-1.30.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-client-2.22.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-common-2.22.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jersey-server-2.22.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jets3t-0.9.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jettison-1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jetty-6.1.14.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jetty-all-7.6.0.v20120127.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jline-2.12.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jodd-core-3.5.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/joni-2.1.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jpam-1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/json-1.8.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/hadoop/share/lib/lib_20190728182750/oozie/json-simple-1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/json4s-ast_2.11-3.2.11.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/json4s-core_2.11-3.2.11.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/json4s-jackson_2.11-3.2.11.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jsp-api-2.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jta-1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jtransforms-2.4.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/libfb303-0.9.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.6.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/log4j-api-2.6.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/log4j-core-2.6.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/log4j-web-2.6.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/log4j-ym.properties#log4j-ym.properties,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/log4j2.xml#log4j2.xml,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/lz4-java-1.4.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/machinist_2.11-0.6.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/macro-compat_2.11-1.1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/mail-1.4.7.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/metrics-core-3.1.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/metrics-json-3.1.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/metrics-json-3.1.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/metrics-jvm-3.1.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/mina-core-2.0.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/mx4j-3.0.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/hadoop/share/lib/lib_20190728182750/oozie/oozie-hadoop-utils-hadoop-2-4.3.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/oozie-sharelib-hive2-4.3.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/hadoop/share/lib/lib_20190728182750/oozie/oozie-sharelib-oozie-4.3.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/oozie-sharelib-spark-4.3.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/orc-core-1.3.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/parquet-column-1.8.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/parquet-common-1.8.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/parquet-encoding-1.8.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/parquet-format-2.3.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/parquet-hadoop-1.8.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.6.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.8.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/parquet-jackson-1.8.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/pmml-model-1.2.15.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/pmml-schema-1.2.15.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/py4j-0.10.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/pyrolite-4.13.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/scala-compiler-2.11.8.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/scala-library-2.11.8.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/scalap-2.11.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/shapeless_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/slider-core-0.90.2-incubating.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-catalyst_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-graphx_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-hive_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-kvstore_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-launcher_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-mllib-local_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-mllib_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-network-common_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-network-shuffle_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-repl_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-sketch_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-sql_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-streaming_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-tags_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.3.2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spire-macros_2.11-0.13.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spire_2.11-0.13.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/stream-2.7.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/super-csv-2.2.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/tephra-api-0.6.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/tephra-core-0.6.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/tephra-hbase-compat-1.0-0.6.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/transaction-api-1.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/twill-api-0.6.0-incubating.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/twill-common-0.6.0-incubating.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/twill-core-0.6.0-incubating.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/twill-discovery-api-0.6.0-incubating.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/twill-discovery-core-0.6.0-incubating.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/twill-zookeeper-0.6.0-incubating.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/univocity-parsers-2.2.1.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/unused-1.0.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/xz-1.0.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/zkclient-0.3.jar,hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar,spark-log4j.properties,hive-site.xml
                    --conf
                    spark.yarn.jars=hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/spark-yarn_2.11-2.3.2.jar
                    --verbose
                    hdfs://HDFS80599/user/root/batchtest/spark/lib/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The **expected** result is below. can output utf-8 log:

**TestLogJob:41 - This is from log.info|zhong wen (中文)**

```
Log Type: stderr

Log Upload Time: Mon Aug 26 10:05:38 +0800 2019

Log Length: 493

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/0/34352/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/service/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Log Type: stdout

Log Upload Time: Mon Aug 26 10:05:38 +0800 2019

Log Length: 286

2019-08-26 10:05:05 INFO  AbstractTbSparkSqlJob:130 - tb.spark.prod.env=true
2019-08-26 10:05:05 INFO  AbstractTbSparkSqlJob:131 - tb.spark.test.env=false
2019-08-26 10:05:36 INFO  TestLogJob:41 - This is from log.info|zhong wen (中文)
```

The **wrong** log example like this below. **Driver use Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties**

and so that log content is not utf-8 :

**TestLogJob:41 - This is from log.info|zhong wen (??)**

```
Log Type: stderr

Log Upload Time: Mon Aug 26 10:05:37 +0800 2019

Log Length: 571

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/41582/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/service/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Log Type: stdout

Log Upload Time: Mon Aug 26 10:05:37 +0800 2019

Log Length: 398

2019-08-26 10:05:05.284 [Driver] INFO  com.stc.data.thingsboard.AbstractTbSparkSqlJob - tb.spark.prod.env=true
2019-08-26 10:05:05.288 [Driver] INFO  com.stc.data.thingsboard.AbstractTbSparkSqlJob - tb.spark.test.env=false
2019-08-26 10:05:36.599 [Driver] INFO  com.stc.data.thingsboard.jobs.example.TestLogJob - This is from log.info|zhong wen (??)
```

Answer (score 0):

The spark job is supposed to be able to be launched from any node, however, your config file is not accessible by any node.

You can pass it to your spark action ! (This is available from `spark-action:0.2`)

```
<action name='spark-node'>
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <job-xml>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/spark/hive-site.xml</job-xml>
        <master>${master}</master>
    <mode>cluster</mode>
        <name>spark-test-oozie</name>
        <class>com.stc.data.thingsboard.jobs.example.TestLogJob</class>
        <jar>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/spark/lib/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar>
    <spark-opts>--driver-memory 1g --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 1g --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-ym.properties -Dtb.spark.prod.env=true </spark-opts>
    <file>path/to/log4j-ym.properties#log4j-ym.properties</file>
    </spark>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I can submit spark job by oozie, using oozie -config job.properties -run. And the oozie workspace is updloaded to hdfs.So all node can load the job.

Comment: @alen, Each node can submit the job, but can they find the file ? I think not, thats why you need the `file` tag :)

Comment: file tag is usefull. But Here I use a trick. I put log4j config file in lib directory, so that the config file is in classpath. From the oozie log, I can verify it. I have paste the log above. The log is too long to notice that.

Comment: @alen I do not really like this solution since it will be harder to change your log file when needed (you need to redeploy), but if it works this is the most important ! :)

Comment: @alen If you found the answer helpful, do not hesitate to upvote

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem , although not completely.

When I add -Dlog4j.debug=true , I can find more debug log from log4j.

below is from 172.12.0.27 , log is right.

```
Log Type: stderr

Log Upload Time: Mon Aug 26 17:07:39 +0800 2019

Log Length: 493

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/0/36267/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/service/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Log Type: stdout

Log Upload Time: Mon Aug 26 17:07:39 +0800 2019

Log Length: 1445

log4j: Trying to find [log4j-ym.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
log4j: Using URL [file:/data/emr/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1565412953433_3905/container_e22_1565412953433_3905_01_000002/log4j-ym.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/data/emr/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1565412953433_3905/container_e22_1565412953433_3905_01_000002/log4j-ym.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[WARN, stdout].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category root set to WARN
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [encoding] to [UTF-8].
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Parsing for [com.stc.data] with value=[INFO].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category com.stc.data set to INFO
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.stc.data=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
2019-08-26 17:07:06 INFO  AbstractTbSparkSqlJob:130 - tb.spark.prod.env=true
2019-08-26 17:07:06 INFO  AbstractTbSparkSqlJob:131 - tb.spark.test.env=false
2019-08-26 17:07:37 INFO  TestLogJob:41 - This is from log.info|zhong wen (中文)
```

below is from 172.12.0.20, and log is not right.

```
Log Type: stderr

Log Upload Time: Mon Aug 26 17:07:34 +0800 2019

Log Length: 19110

DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0.051332 seconds to load 209 plugins from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 44 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting LoggerContext[name=629f0666, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3bf9ce3e]...
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration started for context[name=629f0666] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3bf9ce3e) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'ConfigurationFactory' found 4 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Yaml support
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@66d3eec0
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.yml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.yaml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.json] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.jsn] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.xml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test629f0666.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.yml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.yaml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.json] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.jsn] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.xml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2629f0666.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.json] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.json] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@629f0666.
DEBUG StatusLogger Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/42404/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger Installed script engines
DEBUG StatusLogger Scala Interpreter Version: 1.0, Language: Scala, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {scala}
DEBUG StatusLogger Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_191, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 119 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger No scheduled items
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 14 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
TRACE StatusLogger TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/42404/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 44 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 44 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-2
DEBUG StatusLogger ConsoleAppender$Builder(PatternLayout(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n), Filter=null, target="SYSTEM_OUT", name="Console", follow="null", direct="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenders(={Console})
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="Console", level="null", Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLogger(additivity="false", level="INFO", name="com.stc.data", includeLocation="null", ={Console}, ={}, Configuration(jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/42404/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="Console", level="null", Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", includeLocation="null", ={Console}, ={}, Configuration(jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/42404/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLoggers(={com.stc.data, root})
DEBUG StatusLogger Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/42404/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/log4j2.xml] initialized
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/42404/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/42404/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/log4j2.xml] OK.
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@128d2484...
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@128d2484 OK
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@20765ed5
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering context (1/1): '629f0666' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3bf9ce3e
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=StatusLogger'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=ContextSelector'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=Loggers,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=Appenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=StatusLogger
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=ContextSelector
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=Loggers,name=
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=Loggers,name=com.stc.data
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=629f0666,component=Appenders,name=Console
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
TRACE StatusLogger Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration complete for context[name=629f0666] at URI jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/42404/tb-sql-analysis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3bf9ce3e) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerContext[name=629f0666, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3bf9ce3e] started OK.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/emr/yarn/local/filecache/42556/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/service/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Log Type: stdout

Log Upload Time: Mon Aug 26 17:07:34 +0800 2019

Log Length: 398

2019-08-26 17:07:01.622 [Driver] INFO  com.stc.data.thingsboard.AbstractTbSparkSqlJob - tb.spark.prod.env=true
2019-08-26 17:07:01.650 [Driver] INFO  com.stc.data.thingsboard.AbstractTbSparkSqlJob - tb.spark.test.env=false
2019-08-26 17:07:32.600 [Driver] INFO  com.stc.data.thingsboard.jobs.example.TestLogJob - This is from log.info|zhong wen (??)
This is from System.out.println |zhong wen (??)
```

So, **I find the other nodes alway try to find log4j2 config file**. Although I don't know why, but I try to add **log4j2.configurationFile**. and the other two nodes can log utf8 character correctly.

```
<spark-opts>--driver-memory 1g --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 1g --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-ym.properties -Dtb.spark.prod.env=true -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2-ym.xml</spark-opts>
```

Comment: I might not have been clear but this is what I meant, the log4j is not accessible everywhere, this is why I wanted to put the tag `<file>`. Thanks to it, the file is copied on every nodes, and so is accessible.